# How to hide running applications in Activities?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I would like to hide certain running applications in **Activies**, the view that shows up when one presses the `Win`(`Super`) button. I want the application to be still visible in the **Dash** bar, but stays hidden when I cycle throw the running applications with `Win + Tab`.

Comment: You can use multiple "workspaces" and move those unwanted applications to the *secondary workspace* while you are working on the *primary workspace*.

Comment: Thanks! That perfectly solves my problem!